# How to use Drush for Particular Project?

Tags: drush

In my *loalhost* there are few [drupal 7](http://ftp.drupal.org/files/projects/drupal-7.38.tar.gz) sites installed.

Suppose I have projects A,B and C then how to use for A,B Or C etc.

How to use [Drush](https://www.drupal.org/project/drush) by project wise?

Answer (score 1):

Goto each project folder to run drush command as project wise.
If you are using multi-site goto the project folder under sites directory and execute your drush command.

Comment: When i am trying to use drush command then it is always showing some error with this message connect the database through a socket. The socket file may be
wrong or the php-cli may have no access to it in a jailed shell. See
http://drupal.org/node/1428638 for details

Answer (score 1):

Go to the project root directory and run the drush commands.

For eg:

For Project A,

Go to root directory i.e  `cd var/www/html/A`(may vary) and run the drush commands.

```
$:/var/www/html/A drush cc
```